# How do I open an Android Xamarin application from another Android Xamarin application?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-intent, xamarin, instagram

I am trying to open my Android Xamarin application after I have launched the Instagram application. To open Instagram I am using:

```
Intent InstagramIntent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
                StartActivity(InstagramIntent);
```

How do I open my own application or another Android Xamarin application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-android/

Or specifically for android you can use an intent filter, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.IntentFilterAttribute/

Comment: Would it not be possible to an Intent in the same way as above? How would I find the uri for my application?

Comment: your package name (com.whatever.whatever) will be in your project properties